# Failed to refresh component on click in livewire

Tags: php, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

Tried all the possible solution to refresh the component but failed. Is there any option not to push the new comments and refresh the $comments variable whatever it contains?

Want to refresh $comments and its relation with replies in the blade on click of the send button

Calling $refresh action on the send button but it doesn't seem to work. Even tried to re-render the component with $this->render(). This also fails.

```
<div>
    @foreach($comments as $item)
    <div class="row" @if($item->reply_id != null) style="margin-left:40px;" @endif>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="py-md-4 py-3 border_bottom" >
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-1">
                <div class="rating_person pt-3">
                    <img src="{{ isset($item->owner->profile_picture) ? asset($item->owner->profile_picture) : asset('images/default.jpg') }}">
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-11 col-sm-12 col-12">
                <div class="rating_view_here_content_single_border">
                    <div class="rating_view_here_content_single">
                    <div class="rating_view_stars d-flex justify-content-between pt-3">
                        <div class="rating_view_heading">
                        <h4>{{ $item->owner->name }}</h4>
                        <div class="rating_wrapper">
                            <a href="#" class="grey_rating active-rating">
                            <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </a>
                            <a href="#" class="grey_rating active-rating">
                            <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </a>
                            <a href="#" class="grey_rating active-rating">
                            <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </a>
                            <a href="#" class="grey_rating active-rating">
                            <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </a>
                            <a href="#" class="grey_rating active-rating">
                            <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <span class="rating_days">{{ \App\Library\Helper::getTime($item->created_at) }}</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="rating_comment_here pt-3">
                        <p>{{ $item->comment }}</p>
                        <p>
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="reply" data-id="{{ $item->id }}" wire:click="toggleCommentBox({{ $item->id }}, 'true')">
                            <i class="fa fa-reply" aria-hidden="true"></i> <span>Reply</span>
                        </a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    @if($item_id == $item->id && $show=="true")
                        <div class="video_inner_form_wrapper commentBox-{{ $item->id }}">
                            <form wire:submit.prevent="sendReply" class="row">
                            <input type="hidden" name="reply_id" value="{{ $item->id }}">
                            <div class="comment_input col-md-8">
                            <input type="text" class="bluish_label video_inner_input @error('replyText') is-invalid @enderror" wire:model.lazy="replyText" placeholder="Write your comment here">
                            @error('replyText')
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">{{$message}}</div>
                            @enderror
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn_edit text-uppercase" wire:click="$refresh">Send</a>
                                <button type="button" class="btn_edit text-uppercase cancel" wire:click="toggleCommentBox({{ $item->id }}, 'false')">Cancel</a>
                            </div></form>
                        </div>
                    @endif
                    </div>
                </div> 
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <livewire:frontend.discussion-chat :key="'chat-' . $item->id" :comments="$item->replies" :id="$model_id" :type="$model_type" />
        </div>
    </div>
    @endforeach
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since none of the properties is updated, the livewire chat component will not refresh.

Possible solution is not to pass the list as a param but fetch it inside the chat component. Use events to trigger a refresh:

```
@click="$emit('discussion.chat.{{ $id }}.refresh')"
```

Inside `frontend.discussion-chat` have a

```
public function listeners(): array
{
    return [
        "discussion.chat.$this->id.refresh" => "reload"
    ];
}

public function reload(): void
{
    // E.g.
    $this->comments->fresh();
}
```

Comment: it is the child component and now i have set the event and listening it in parent with refresh. It works good. Though your idea i didn't understood really, if you could elaborate more that would be great. Thanks

Comment: i suggest you can format well your event to $emit('discussion.chat.refresh, passtheidhere), and in the then expect that value in the reload function reload($id)

Comment: also in livewire you can just introduce instance variable protected $listeners = ["discussion.chat.refresh" => "reload"]

Comment: @AliaJain You have a child component that receives the chat ID as a paramter and loads all the comments into an eloquent collection. The child component will listen for the refresh event and reload the comments. That event can be fired from the parent or any other place in your application.

Comment: Ok, thanks all. Though solved the problem by calling event from child and listening in parent